# Same look for 2 different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-tokeninput

I was looking for jQ plug-in which gives same result as StackOverflow tags. Found one using Tokeninput.

Please take  a look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/nXxZW/3/.

And now, look at this screenshots:

**Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

As you see, input text element looks a bit different on browsers.

What I'm trying to get is, exactly same look to `ul` element as `input text` with CSS (I mean, width, border, inset shadow.. etc. Tried but can't figure out what am I missing) or plugin modification to get same result in input text box rather than ul li structure (like Stackoverflow tags. I think it's a bit difficult to achieve.) Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are talking about the text looking different, there's nothing you can do about that. As far as the input element, give it a border and they will both look very similar.

Comment: @KevinB I need width to be same as Ul. It must fill remaining width just as UL

Comment: Inspect the element with a debugging console and copy the applied styles then apply them via css to the target input.

Comment: @KevinB Tried. Ul is dynamically changing. Try on your browser you'll see

Comment: All you have to do is give it a border, a width, and proper padding. Give it a shot.

Comment: @KevinB Have you even read my comment? `Input text` must fill remaining width just as `UL`. I can't achieve this result. If you can please help

Comment: The ul isn't filling the remaining width, it is using a set min-width.

Comment: Nevermind, it is growing. hmm... you could use a 100% width on the input with margins,

Comment: Looks like the biggest problem right now is that the input's size attribute overrides block being 100% width, and setting it to 100% causes it to overflow due to inner-padding. Looks like you are goign to have to rely on javascript.

Comment: It isn't perfect, but it works, http://jsfiddle.net/nXxZW/13/

Comment: Here it is without javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/nXxZW/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for both inputs, add border: 1px solid #ddd; and also background: white;

that will force the inputs to have the same effect

Comment: I need width to be same as Ul. It must fill remaining width just as UL.

Comment: it doesnt work if the browser is small because you also need to add the same min-width as you do on the upper unordered list (add it to mail_credentials)

Answer (score 1):

If its just the input field that you are worried about then try adding width, height and border properties to the CSS of mail_credentials like this:

```
.mail_credentials{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 0 15px 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: I need width to be same as Ul. It must fill remaining width just as UL